# React router PrivateRoute keeps redirecting to the login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

I'm having problem with **privateRoute** it should be redirecting to the Home page after signin but it keeps redirecting to '/signin' page. everything is working fine if I remove PrivateRoute im not sure I'm beginner with react and it's my first time using firebase auth is there any way to fix this problem I'm sorry my code is messy

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import  StyledFirebaseAuth  from 'react-firebaseui/FirebaseAuth'
import { Redirect, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useAuth } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';



var uiconfig = {
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInSuccessUrl:'/',
    signInOptions : [
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID],
    callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
            return true;
          }
    }
};

const signOut = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function(){
        return console.log('signout');
    }).catch(() => {
        console.error("error signout");
    })
    return <Redirect to='/signin'></Redirect>
}
var Cuser = null

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(false)
    const {currentUser} = useAuth()
    console.log(Cuser)

      return (
      <Route {...rest} render={props => {
        if(Cuser){
          return <Component {...props}></Component>       
      } else {
        return <Redirect to="/signin" />
      }
  }} ></Route>)
}

const Signup = () => {
    const {history} = useHistory()
    useEffect(() => {
        const authOberver = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            setUser(user)
            
        });
        return authOberver
    })
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    
    if(user){
        axios.post("http://localhost:4000/notes", {
          email: user.email,
        })
        Cuser = true
    }    
    return (
        <>
            <div>Signin / Register</div>
            <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiconfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}></StyledFirebaseAuth>
        </>
    )
}

export {signOut}
export default Signup; 
export {PrivateRoute};
```

I tried to create a separate file for current user and using **currentUser** to check if the user is logged in or not but still happing the same problem

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import firebase from "firebase";
import axios from 'axios'
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth'

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribed = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    })
    return unsubscribed
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
  };
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem might lie with how you save Cuser. Why not handle it in a state/context?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the variable `Cuser` to decide what component to render. So even if `Cuser` is set to true after signup, when the component gets re-rendered, it's value gets back to being `null` which is why it goes to `else {return <Redirect to="/signin" />}` block.

You can modify you AuthContext to store the login status in state. In below code, lets say `cUser`:

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  cont [cUser, setCUser] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribed = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    })
    return unsubscribed
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    cUser: cUser,
    setCUser: setCUser,
  };
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}
```

And then use setCUser to set and check the value

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import  StyledFirebaseAuth  from 'react-firebaseui/FirebaseAuth'
import { Redirect, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useAuth } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';



var uiconfig = {
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInSuccessUrl:'/',
    signInOptions : [
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID],
    callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
            return true;
          }
    }
};

const signOut = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function(){
        setCUser(false);
        return console.log('signout');
    }).catch(() => {
        console.error("error signout");
    })
    return <Redirect to='/signin'></Redirect>
}
var Cuser = null

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(false)
    const {currentUser, cUser, setCUser} = useAuth()
    console.log(Cuser)

      return (
      <Route {...rest} render={props => {
        if(cUser){
          return <Component {...props}></Component>       
      } else {
        return <Redirect to="/signin" />
      }
  }} ></Route>)
}

const Signup = () => {
    const {history} = useHistory()
    useEffect(() => {
        const authOberver = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            setUser(user)
            
        });
        return authOberver
    })
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    
    if(user){
        axios.post("http://localhost:4000/notes", {
          email: user.email,
        })
        setCUser(true);
    }    
    return (
        <>
            <div>Signin / Register</div>
            <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiconfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}></StyledFirebaseAuth>
        </>
    )
}

export {signOut}
export default Signup; 
export {PrivateRoute};
```

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can use state in AuthContext to store the login status

Comment: im sorry but im still having the same problem it keeps redirecting to signin page i tried to log currentUser and it is showing it undefined but it is working on other pages same thing with CUser because it is false it keeps redirecting to signin page